# Tkinter window is not getting displyed when used before while True loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, do-while

I am using a Raspberry Pi to create a dashboard. When not using a while True loop, the Tkinter window pops up as required. However, it does not pop up when I use it before the `while` loop. My code is as below:

```py
import FillingMachineClass
import datetime
import threading

import tkinter
sc = tkinter.Tk()

fm = FillingMachineClass.FillingMachine(1)
thread_zero_detect = threading.Thread(target = fm.detect_zero_sensor)
thread_carousel_opertion = threading.Thread(target = fm.carousel_opertion)
thread_line_jamming = threading.Thread(target = fm.line_jamming)
t1 = [threading.Thread(target = fm.detect_zero_sensor)]
t2 = [threading.Thread(target = fm.carousel_opertion)]
t3 = [threading.Thread(target = fm.line_jamming)]

while True:
    
    if t1[0].is_alive() == False:
        t1.append(threading.Thread(target = fm.detect_zero_sensor))
        t1[1].start()
        t1.pop(0)
    if t2[0].is_alive() == False:
        t2.append(threading.Thread(target = fm.carousel_opertion))
        t2[1].start()
        t2.pop(0)  
    if t3[0].is_alive() == False:
        t3.append(threading.Thread(target = fm.line_jamming))
        t3[1].start()
        t3.pop(0)
sc.mainloop()
```

Comment: `while True:` is an endless loop. How do you expect the program to reach `sc.mainloop()`?

Comment: What you need is using while loop inside the threaded tasks instead.

Answer (score 0):

As the while loop will run forever, `sc.mainloop()` will not be executed.

What you need is using while loop inside the threaded tasks instead:

```py
import threading
import tkinter
import FillingMachineClass

class Task(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, func):
        super().__init__()
        self.func = func
        self.stop_flag = threading.Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.stop_flag.is_set():
            self.func()

    def terminate(self):
        self.stop_flag.set()

sc = tkinter.Tk()

fm = FillingMachineClass.FillingMachine(1)
# create the tasks and store the task object in a list
tasklist = []
for func in (fm.detect_zero_sensor, fm.carousel_opertion, fm.line_jamming):
    tasklist.append(Task(func))
    tasklist[-1].start()

sc.mainloop()

# terminate the tasks
for task in tasklist:
    task.terminate()
```